# nottype not working

Tags: biblatex

I have an issue with the `nottype=type` command with BibLaTeX.

This is the code I have:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    %natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=verbose,
    maxcitenames=50,
    maxbibnames=50,
    firstinits=false,
    sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio} 


\section{Références}
\subsection{Monographie}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=nonenottype=online, nottype=booklet, nottype=misc, nottype=techreport, nottype=manual]
\subsection{Webograhie}
\printbibliography[heading=none,type=online]
\subsection{Documents électroniques (PDF)}
\printbibliography[heading=none,nottype=online nottype=misc, nottype=inproceedings, nottype=book, nottype=misc, nottype=article]
\subsection{Iconographie}
\printbibliography[heading=none,type=misc]
```

And this is my `.bib` file:

```
@techreport{rfc8555,
  author={Barnes, Richard and Hoffman-Andrews, Jacob and Kasten, James},
  title = "{Automatic Certificate Management Environment (ACME)}",
  howpublished = {Internet Requests for Comments},
  type="{RFC}",
  number=8555,
  pages = {1-95},
  year = {2019},
  month = {Mars},
  issn = {2070-1721},
  publisher = "{RFC Editor}",
  institution = "{RFC Editor}",
  url={https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc8555.pdf}
}

@inproceedings{tiefenau2019usability,
  title={A Usability Evaluation of Let's Encrypt and Certbot: Usable Security Done Right},
  author={Tiefenau, Christian and von Zezschwitz, Emanuel and H{\"a}ring, Maximilian and Krombholz, Katharina and Smith, Matthew},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 2019 ACM SIGSAC Conference on Computer and Communications Security},
  pages={1971--1988},
  year={2019},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

But the `nottype=techreport` is not working, the items in my `.bib` file categorized as `@techreport` are displayed in two categories in my bibliography even if one of them rejects this type of object.

Comment: There are various commas missing in your code. E.g. here `nottype=online nottype=misc`. Also your code is incomplete and so can not be tested directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`techreport` is defined as an alias for `report`. To exclude `techreport` from a specific bibliography, use `nottype=report`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=verbose,
    maxcitenames=50,
    maxbibnames=50,
    firstinits=false,
    sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{rfc8555,
  author={Barnes, Richard and Hoffman-Andrews, Jacob and Kasten, James},
  title = "{Automatic Certificate Management Environment (ACME)}",
  howpublished = {Internet Requests for Comments},
  type="{RFC}",
  number=8555,
  pages = {1-95},
  year = {2019},
  month = {Mars},
  issn = {2070-1721},
  publisher = "{RFC Editor}",
  institution = "{RFC Editor}",
  url={https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc8555.pdf}
}
@inproceedings{tiefenau2019usability,
  title={A Usability Evaluation of Let's Encrypt and Certbot: Usable Security Done Right},
  author={Tiefenau, Christian and von Zezschwitz, Emanuel and H{\"a}ring, Maximilian and Krombholz, Katharina and Smith, Matthew},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 2019 ACM SIGSAC Conference on Computer and Communications Security},
  pages={1971--1988},
  year={2019},
  organization={ACM}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{References}
\subsection{Monographie}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none ,nottype=online, nottype=booklet, nottype=misc, nottype=report, nottype=manual]
\subsection{Documents electroniques (PDF)}
\printbibliography[heading=none, nottype=online, nottype=misc, nottype=inproceedings, nottype=book, nottype=misc, nottype=article]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know that !

Comment: Ah man, thank you so much. I now know both how to write correct `urldate`s and how to filter the types.